# All elements are getting aligned center with the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, center

This navbar has caused me many problems. This time I am facing a different kind of issue again and maybe the most difficult.

The navbar should be at the center but not the other elements after it. You can even see the previous questions posted by me on this topic, which were related to the navbar overflowing on all the elements (all elements are going below). Solved that issue but again got a new one.

Here is the full HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Smileybook</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="buttonstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">



<style>
div {
  margin-bottom: ;
  padding: ;
}
.info {
 clear: both;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 700px;
 background-color: #e7f3fe;
 border-left: 6px solid #2196F3;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}
.closebtn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
</style>

<style>
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px lightblue;
  border-radius: ;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: ;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #333;
}
</style>


<style>
.buttonhover {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(2, 0, 200) 0%, rgb(9, 9, 121) 0%, rgb(0, 212, 255) 100%);;
  border: solid;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 135px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.buttonhover span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.buttonhover span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.buttonhover:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.buttonhover:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
</style>

<style>
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #2FEA14;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #FFF300;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 5; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: manual; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: ;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 5px ;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)}
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>

</head>

</div>




<div class"header-container">

<ul id="nav-1">
    <li class="slide1"></li>
    <li class="slide2"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Alpha</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gamma</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Epsilon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Login</a></li>
  </ul>











  <div class="info">
     <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
     <b>Info!</b> You are currently on latest version of Smileybook
     <i>Smileybook 1.2</i>
     Subscribe to Smileybook Notifications and Share you comments on Mail.
   </div>



<div id="id01" class="modal" align="center">


   <form class="modal-content animate" action="https://yashdamani.000webhostapp.com/account/account.html">


<div class="imgcontainer">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close ">&times;</span>
</div>



  <div class="container">
  <label><b><i><font color="70bafe">Username</font></i></b>
</label>

     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"name="user" required>




    <label><b><i><font color="70bafe" >Password</font></i></b></label>

   <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>


<a href="https://yashdamani.000webhostapp.com/account/account.html" accesskey="enter">
<button class="btn submit_btn form-control" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:20px," type="submit">Login</button></a>

<br>


 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<font color="70bafe" > Remember me
  </font>
</div>



 <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">

  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">
<font color="0A026A"><b>Cancel</b></font></button>


<br>


<a href="https://yashdamani.000webhostapp.com/forgotpassword.html"  accesskey="" ><font color="70bafe" > Forgot Password?</a></font>

<hr color="70bafe">

</div>


</div>

 </form>


</div>





 <script>
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
         modal.style.display = "none";
     }
 }

 </script>



 <script>
 var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
   close[i].onclick = function(){
     var div = this.parentElement;
     div.style.opacity = "0";
     setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
   }
 }
 </script>

  <script src='./jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>


</body>





</html>
```

And here are the CSS codes for the navbar:

```
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#nav-1 {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: none;
  border-radius: 20em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 20px 40px 40px #00000033;
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav-1 li {
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav-1 li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

#nav-1 .slide1,
#nav-1 .slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1.05);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1.05);
}

#nav-1 .slide1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 2;
}

#nav-1 .slide2 {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

#nav-1 .squeeze {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: white;
}
```

Please help me out as early as possible.

Comment: Do you have a working snipper, codepen or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Smileybook</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="buttonstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">



<style>
div {
  margin-bottom: ;
  padding: ;
}
.info {
 clear: both;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #e7f3fe;
 border-left: 6px solid #2196F3;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}
.closebtn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
</style>

<style>
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px lightblue;
  border-radius: ;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: ;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #333;
}
</style>


<style>
.buttonhover {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(2, 0, 200) 0%, rgb(9, 9, 121) 0%, rgb(0, 212, 255) 100%);;
  border: solid;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 135px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.buttonhover span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.buttonhover span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.buttonhover:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.buttonhover:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
</style>

<style>
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #2FEA14;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #FFF300;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 5; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: manual; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: ;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 5px ;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)}
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
<style>

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.nav-cont
{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
#nav-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: none;
  border-radius: 20em;
  display: inline-block;
  //display: -webkit-box;
  //display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 20px 40px 40px #00000033;
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav-1 li {
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav-1 li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

#nav-1 .slide1,
#nav-1 .slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1.05);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1.05);
}

#nav-1 .slide1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 2;
}

#nav-1 .slide2 {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

#nav-1 .squeeze {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          //justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>





<div class="header-container">

<div class="nav-cont">
<ul id="nav-1">
    <li class="slide1"></li>
    <li class="slide2"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Alpha</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gamma</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Epsilon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>











  <div class="info">
     <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
     <b>Info!</b> You are currently on latest version of Smileybook
     <i>Smileybook 1.2</i>
     Subscribe to Smileybook Notifications and Share you comments on Mail.
   </div>



<div id="id01" class="modal" align="center">


   <form class="modal-content animate" action="https://yashdamani.000webhostapp.com/account/account.html">


<div class="imgcontainer">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close ">&times;</span>
</div>



  <div class="container">
  <label><b><i><font color="70bafe">Username</font></i></b>
</label>

     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"name="user" required>




    <label><b><i><font color="70bafe" >Password</font></i></b></label>

   <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>


<a href="https://yashdamani.000webhostapp.com/account/account.html" accesskey="enter">
<button class="btn submit_btn form-control" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:20px," type="submit">Login</button></a>

<br>


 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<font color="70bafe" > Remember me
  </font>
</div>



 <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">

  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">
<font color="0A026A"><b>Cancel</b></font></button>


<br>


<a href="https://yashdamani.000webhostapp.com/forgotpassword.html"  accesskey="" ><font color="70bafe" > Forgot Password?</a></font>

<hr color="70bafe">

</div>


</div>

 </form>


</div>





 <script>
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
         modal.style.display = "none";
     }
 }

 </script>



 <script>
 var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
   close[i].onclick = function(){
     var div = this.parentElement;
     div.style.opacity = "0";
     setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
   }
 }
 </script>

  <script src='./jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>


</body>





</html>
```

Comment: your comment helped me but i am thinking to delete this post which is not possible untill you delete this comment. please delete your suggestion. btw thanks for your help.